# How to aggregate and count avg value by groups from 2 tables in sql?

Tags: sql, inner-join, average, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables , department and employee. I need to get department name and average age of it.

```
create table Dep(name_dep char, id_dep int);

insert into Dep values("econ", 1);
insert into Dep values("credit", 2);
insert into Dep values("energy", 3);
insert into Dep values("retail", 4);
insert into Dep values("manufactury", 5);

create table Emp(id_emp int, id_dep int, age int, person_name char, salary int );
insert into Emp values(1, 1, 23, 'john', 200);
insert into Emp values(3, 2, 3, 'dalbai', 100);
insert into Emp values(6, 3, 53, 'borat', 300);
insert into Emp values(7, 1, 63, 'erjan', 1600);
insert into Emp values(9, 2, 73, 'sergey', 1000);
insert into Emp values(8, 5, 83, 'lucy', 20);
insert into Emp values(90, 4, 93, 'mike', 1200);
```

How to select dept name and avg age of employees in that dept?

```
SELECT name_dep, average_age
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name_dep, AVG(age) AS average_age
    FROM Dep d
    GROUP BY id_dep
) d
    ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having the above table data.

Comment: You can't select `AVG(age)` from the `Dep` table, because the `age` column doesn't exist there. Your subquery needs to select from the `Emp` table.

Comment: @ERJAN is there any reason that you did not accept the earliest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b700c6ebfd862897d63a198f03425bc5)**

```
select name_dep,avg(age)
from emp a inner join dep b on a.id_dep=b.id_dep
group by a.id_dep,name_dep
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, `group by id_dep, name_dep` and then get the average age:

```
select
  d.name_dep, avg(age) average_age
from Dep d inner join Emp e 
on e.id_dep = d.id_dep
group by d.id_dep, d.name_dep
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9DhoFVUTEPr4fa4tK41eH/3).
Results:

```
| name_dep    | average_age |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| econ        | 43          |
| credit      | 38          |
| energy      | 53          |
| retail      | 93          |
| manufactury | 83          |
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
SELECT 
 d.name_dep, AVG(age) as avg_age 
FROM 
 Emp e, Dep d 
WHERE 
 e.id_dep = d.id_dep 
GROUP BY 
 d.name_dep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.name_dep,AVG(e.age)
FROM Dep d JOIN Emp e ON d.id_dep = e.id_dep
GROUP BY d.name_dep;
```